# Kelvin per Kelvin Difference

Tags: bugs, units

**Bug introduced in 9 and partially persists through 10.2 or later**

The specific bug described in the original question is fixed (`"Kelvin"` is correctly recognized as `"Kelvins"` now) but as shown in the [answer by Willinski](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94626/280) there is more involved problem with misinterpretation of `"K"` as `"KelvinsDifference"` in some cases. Please see [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94635/280) for more information on the **temperature difference** units in *Mathematica*.

---

I'm trying to use Mathematica units more often, but I've run into the following problem:

```
    (*Define some unitful constants*)
    q = UnitConvert[Quantity["elementary charge"]];
    k = UnitConvert[Quantity["Boltzmann Constant"]];
    T = Quantity[300, "Kelvin"];
    V = Quantity[5, "Volt"];
    (*Do a simple calculation*)
    UnitConvert[(q V)/(k T)]
```

The above code outputs

```
    Quantity[193.409, ("Kelvins")/("KelvinsDifference")]
```

which really should just be 193.409, since the units cancel, but Mathematica insists on a distinction between absolute temperature and temperature differences.  I understand that such a distinction is useful in conversions, but the above is quite a nuisance.

Is there a way to prevent this?  I'd rather not have to put in `QuantityMagnitude` calls every time I need to cancel some `Kelvins`.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this behaviour has changed: `Kelvin` used to be interpreted by Wolfram Alpha as `KelvinDifference`, whereas `Kelvins` was recognized by Mathematica as a built-in unit and directly interpreted as `Kelvin`. Since a few months, `Kelvin` is interpreted as `Kelvins`, so the error appears to have gone away. (Of course, the unit of the Boltzmann constant is stilll incorrect, see Xerxes' answer.)

Comment: @Martin Although now Wolfram|Alpha correctly interprets `"Kelvin"` as `"Kelvins"`, it still incorrectly interprets `"K"` as `"KelvinsDifference"` in `Quantity[1, "J/(mol*K)"]` while in `Quantity[300, "K"]` it correctly interprets `"K"` as `"Kelvins"` (the example is from the [answer by Willinski](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94626/280)). So the bug is only partially fixed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. The dimensions of the Boltzmann constant are incorrect. In fact, all the physical constants I checked have `TemperatureUnit` where they should have `TemperatureDifferenceUnit`. You should only have to make a substitution when making calls to physical constants in `Quantity`:

```
q = UnitConvert[Quantity["elementary charge"]];
k = (UnitConvert[Quantity["Boltzmann Constant"]] /. 
   "Kelvins" -> "KelvinsDifference");
T = Quantity[300, "Kelvin"];
V = Quantity[5, "Volt"];
UnitConvert[(q V)/(k T)]
(* 193.409 *)
```

EDIT: Alternatively, since `Quantity` seems to be calling away to Alpha, you could do

```
k = UnitConvert[Quantity["Boltzmann Constant (energy per temperature difference)"]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I agree: it makes a lot more sense for those to be `TemperatureDifferenceUnit`.  And your fix solves my problem!

Comment: @Xerxes It seems you misinterpreted the purpose of `"KelvinsDifference"`, please see [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94635/280). The specific bug described in the question is fixed now (`"Kelvin"` is correctly recognized as `"Kelvins"` now) but as shown in the [answer by Willinski](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94626/280) there is more involved problem with misinterpretation of `"K"` as `"KelvinsDifference"` in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

There are other mantraps!

```
f = (p + a/V^2) (V - b) == R T;

params1 = {
   b -> Quantity[0.0364, "L/mol"],
   a -> Quantity[135.8*10^3, "Pa*L^2/mol^2"],
   p -> Quantity[100, "kPa"],
   R -> Quantity[8.314472, "J/(mol*K)"],(*!!!*)
   T -> Quantity[300, "K"]
   };

First@NSolve[f /. params1, V ]
```

*NSolve::units: NSolve was unable to determine the units of quantities that appear in the input.*
[image]

```
params2 = {
   b -> Quantity[0.0364, "L/mol"],
   a -> Quantity[135.8*10^3, "Pa*L^2/mol^2"],
   p -> Quantity[100, "kPa"],
   R -> Quantity[8.314472, "Joules"/ ("Moles"*"Kelvins")],(*!!!*)
   T -> Quantity[300, "K"]
   };
First@NSolve[f /. params2, V ]
{0.0249254 m^3/mol}
```

Answer (score 2):

The general method which allows to avoid such problems is to specify the units in the canonical form and do not rely on the ability of Wolfram|Alpha to interpret your input correctly.

The original problem arose due to misinterpretation of `"Kelvin"` as `"KelvinsDifference"` by Wolfram|Alpha (to which *Mathematica* communicates when you provide an unknown string as a name for a unit). The problem would not appear if instead of incorrect name `"Kelvin"` one would supply the correct name for the absolute temperature units `"Kelvins"`.

The original bug in Wolfram|Alpha is already fixed (`"Kelvin"` is correctly recognized as `"Kelvins"` now) but as shown in the [answer by Willinski](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94626/280) there still persists more involved problem with misinterpretation of `"K"` as `"KelvinsDifference"` in some cases.

For an explanation of the role of `"KelvinsDifference"` in the Wolfram Language please see [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94635/280).