# How to evaluate expression completely?

Tags: evaluation, warning-messages

In MMA 13.2, if we run

```
Quantity[1, 1/"DegreesCelsius"]
```

it automatically throw a message

[image]

But if we run

```
unit = 1/"DegreesCelsius";
Quantity[1, unit]
```

it gives result without message.

[image]

It seems that MMA does not evaluate completely in this case. If we evaluate the output, then it will throw message.

I want to know if there is a function like `completeEvaluate`, so that `completeEvaluate@Quantity[1, unit]` will throw a message.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you are observing is a bug in Quantity. 'Quantity[1, "DegreesCelsius"^(-1)]' is not processed the same way as 'Quantity[1, 1/"DegreesCelsius"]'.

```
In[50]:= Quantity[1, "DegreesCelsius"^(-1)] // InputForm

Out[50]//InputForm=
Quantity[1, "DegreesCelsius"^(-1)]

In[49]:= Quantity[1, 1/"DegreesCelsius"] // InputForm

During evaluation of In[49]:= Quantity::ctunit: Compound unit given with absolute 1/(DegreesCelsius); converting to Kelvins.

Out[49]//InputForm=
Quantity[5483/20, "Kelvins"^(-1)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your observation. I think there is chaos in temperature quantity manipulation as described in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/287389/4742 . Now you add one more example.

Comment: But anyway, this does not solve my problem : )

Comment: It's really not at all chaotic. The only unfortunate thing is that prior to implementing the *Differrence units Mathematica tried to do something sensible with the input instead of rejecting it as unsafe. While @GlennWelch's answer seems to demonstrate a bug, that's not really the core of your problem. To fix your problem, use the units that are appropriate for the semantics you are trying to formalize.